# SSRS - Why isn't my SUM() working correctly?

Tags: sql, reporting-services, syntax

I followed a guide on techonthenet where it says that for a SUM query you need to put the `Sum(expr)` in the `SELECT` statement and then `GROUP BY` every other field you are selecting (psuedo-code; correct me if I'm wrong). Below is my attempt. Why am I getting the error

> **"An error occurred while executing the query. Incorrect syntax near '('. Error:102; Line 9"**

The end result of all this will be a Report, not just a query. In the report, all of the fields below will be shown with the exception that the [Difference] field will be totaled at the bottom. I get the feeling that instead of trying to sum this in the query I should be trying to sum in the report...

**EDIT** - I removed the [ALL] but now I get the error "Cannot use an aggregate or a subquery in an expression used for the group by list of a GROUP BY clause." It also says that this error is on line 29. I will mark it below.

```
SELECT 

    JOB.WHSE,
    LEFT(RESSCHD000.RESID, 6) AS Line,
        RIGHT(LEFT(JOB000.JSID, 11), 10)+ '-' +RIGHT(LEFT(JOB000.JSID, 27), 2) AS [Job Number],
    LEFT(RESSCHD000.STARTDATE, 7)+ '         ' +RIGHT(Convert(Datetime, MIN(RESSCHD000.STARTDATE)), 8) AS [Start],
    LEFT(RESSCHD000.ENDDATE, 7)+ '     ' +RIGHT(Convert(Datetime, MAX(RESSCHD000.ENDDATE)),8) AS [End], 
        RESSCHD000.STATUSCD, 
        Sum((Dateadd("n",DateDiff("n", MIN(RESSCHD000.STARTDATE),MAX(RESSCHD000.ENDDATE)),'00:00:00'))) AS [SumOfDifference], 
        RESSCHD000.JOBTAG,
    CASE
        WHEN    Dateadd("n",DateDiff("n", MIN(RESSCHD000.STARTDATE),MAX(RESSCHD000.ENDDATE)),'00:00:00') > '3:59:00'
                THEN 'Full Sanitation'
        ELSE    'Dry Clean' 
    END AS [Type of Sanitation],
    jrt_sch.Uf_Quoted_Crew_Size AS [Crew Size]

FROM 
        RESSCHD000 INNER JOIN JOB000 ON RESSCHD000.JOBTAG = JOB000.JOBTAG
    INNER JOIN JOB ON JOB.JOB = RIGHT(LEFT(JOB000.JSID, 11), 10) AND JOB.suffix = RIGHT(LEFT(JOB000.JSID, 27), 2)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN jrt_sch ON jrt_sch.job = job.job
WHERE
    job.job_date = @job_date

GROUP BY 
    JOB.WHSE,
    LEFT(RESSCHD000.RESID, 6),
    RIGHT(LEFT(JOB000.JSID, 11), 10)+ '-' +RIGHT(LEFT(JOB000.JSID, 27), 2), --line 29
    LEFT(RESSCHD000.STARTDATE, 7)+ '         ' +RIGHT(Convert(Datetime, MIN(RESSCHD000.STARTDATE)), 8),
    LEFT(RESSCHD000.ENDDATE, 7)+ '     ' +RIGHT(Convert(Datetime, MAX(RESSCHD000.ENDDATE)),8), 
    RESSCHD000.STATUSCD, 
    RESSCHD000.JOBTAG,
    CASE
        WHEN    Dateadd("n",DateDiff("n", MIN(RESSCHD000.STARTDATE),MAX(RESSCHD000.ENDDATE)),'00:00:00') > '3:59:00'
                THEN 'Full Sanitation'
        ELSE    'Dry Clean' 
    END,
    jrt_sch.Uf_Quoted_Crew_Size

HAVING 
                RESSCHD000.STATUSCD='s'
```

Comment: please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
And [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: what are you trying to get the sum of?  `Sum([All] DateAdd())` doesnt really make sense

Comment: First of all you can make this wall of text human readable

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to this line:

```
Sum([ALL] (Dateadd("n",DateDiff("n", MIN(RESSCHD000.STARTDATE),MAX(RESSCHD000.ENDDATE)),'00:00:00'))) AS [SumOfDifference]
```

The sum is looking for a field (or formula of some sort) to SUM up. You have a field name followed by a formula. I am guessing you want the sum of the difference in seconds based on the FIELD name (SumOfDifference).

I think you just need to remove the **[ALL]**.

```
SUM(DATEADD("n",DATEDIFF("n", MIN(RESSCHD000.STARTDATE), MAX(RESSCHD000.ENDDATE)),'00:00:00')) AS [SumOfDifference]
```

Comment: Hmm...still getting an error, albeit a different one. See edited answer.

Comment: Ahh - you have a MIN and MAX as part of your Start and End fields. You can try removing them from the Group By. If that doesn;t work you can break the LEFT part into it's separate column and GROUP BY it and have the RIGHT Min/Max as another column.